# Android 8 Oreo Wifi Disconnect event with SupplicantState

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-8.0-oreo

I have registered receiver to get wifi events with `android.net.wifi.supplicant.STATE_CHANGE` action. Below Android 8 it is working fine on all devices but on Oreo, I am not able to receive any action on wifi disconnect. It broadcasts action on Wifi state change but not on disconnect.

To register Supplicant State Event

```
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
```

To receive Supplicant State Event

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    SboxnwLogs.printLog("Received Supplicant State Event :"+intent.getAction());

    SupplicantState newState = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE);
}
```

So there is no action for wifi disconnect on Android 8 oreo.